# Unit testing functions with global variables in R

Tags: r, unit-testing, global-variables, r-package

## Preamble: package structure

I have an R package that contains an `R/globals.R` file with the following content (simplified):

```r
utils::globalVariables("COUNTS")
```

Then I have a function that simply uses this variable. For example, `R/addx.R` contains a function that adds a number to `COUNTS`

```r
addx <- function(x) {
    COUNTS + x
}
```

This is all fine when doing a `devtools::check()` on my package, there's no complaining about `COUNTS` being out of the scope of `addx()`.

## Problem: writing a unit test

However, say I also have a `tests/testthtat/test-addx.R` file with the following content:

```
test_that("addition works", expect_gte(fun(1), 1))
```

The content of the test doesn't really matter here, because when running `devtools::test()` I get an "object 'COUNTS' not found" error.

What am I missing? How can I correctly write this test (or setup my package).

## What I've tried to solve the problem

1. Adding `utils::globalVariables("COUNTS")` to `R/addx.R`, either before, inside or after the function definition.
2. Adding `utils::globalVariables("COUNTS")` to `tests/testthtat/test-addx.R` in all places I could think of.
3. Manually initializing `COUNTS` (e.g., with `COUNTS <- 0` or `<<- 0`) in all places of `tests/testthtat/test-addx.R` I could think of.
4. Reading some examples from other packages on GitHub that use a similar syntax ([source](https://github.com/search?p=1&q=utils%3A%3AglobalVariables&type=Code&utf8=)).

Comment: Is `COUNTS` literally defined in one of `yourpackage/R/*.R`, outside of function definitions?

Comment: The alternative situation I can think of is that you expect `COUNTS` to be defined in the calling environment. If this is the case, then ... I think the answer is "don't do that".

Comment: @r2evans, there are a couple of functions that perform assignments to `COUNTS`. `clearGlobal()` basically initializes it as `COUNTS <- vector()` and `updateGlobal()` recalculates `COUNTS` as a function of other passed arguments. AFAIK, there are no instances of `COUNTS` being defined _outside_ of a function definition (this is a huge project I'm not 100% acquanted with). I think the case we have here is the one from your second comment, which I agree is not ideal, but I'm afraid I'll break something if I change the implemented dynamic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you misunderstand what `utils::globalVariables("COUNTS")` does.  It just declares that `COUNTS` is a global variable, so when the code analysis sees

```
addx <- function(x) {
    COUNTS + x
}
```

it won't complain about the use of an undefined variable.  However, it is up to you to actually create the variable, for example by an explicit

```
COUNTS <- 0
```

somewhere in your source.  I think if you do that, you won't even need the `utils::globalVariables("COUNTS")` call, because the code analysis will see the global definition.

Where you would need it is when you're doing some nonstandard evaluation, so that it's not obvious where a variable comes from. Then you declare it as a global, and the code analysis won't worry about it.  For example, you might get a warning about

```
subset(df, Col1 < 0)
```

because it appears to use a global variable named `Col1`, but of course that's fine, because the `subset()` function evaluates in a non-standard way, letting you include column names without writing `df$Col`.

Comment: Thanks, adding `COUNTS <- vector()` on the same script as `globalVariables()` (for convenience) solved the issue. I could swear I tried this (see point 3 of the OP), but I'm just glad it's working. Fingers crossed it doesn't break something downstream. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

@user2554330's answer is great for many things.

If I understand correctly, you have a `COUNTS` that needs to be updateable, so putting it in the package environment might be an issue.

One technique you can use is the use of local environments.

Two alternatives:

1. If it will always be referenced in one function, it might be easiest to change the function from

   ```r
   myfunc <- function(...) {
     # do something
     COUNTS <- COUNTS + 1
   }
   ```

   to

   ```r
   myfunc <- local({
     COUNTS <- NA
     function(...) {
       # do something
       COUNTS <<- COUNTS + 1
     }
   })
   ```

   What this does is create a local environment "around" `myfunc`, so when it looks for `COUNTS`, it will be found immediately. Note that it reassigns using `<<-` instead of `<-`, since the latter would not update the different-environment-version of the variable.

   You can actually access this `COUNTS` from another function in the package:

   ```r
   otherfunc <- function(...) {
     COUNTScopy <- get("COUNTS", envir = environment(myfunc))
     COUNTScopy <- COUNTScopy + 1
     assign("COUNTS", COUNTScopy, envir = environment(myfunc))
   }
   ```

   (Feel free to name it `COUNTS` here as well, I used a different name to highlight that it doesn't matter.)

   While the use of `get` and `assign` is a little inconvenient, it should only be required twice per function that needs to do this.

   Note that the user *can* get to this if needed, but they'll need to use similar mechanisms. Perhaps that's a problem; in my packages where I need some form of persistence like this, I have used convenience getter/setter functions.
2. You can place an environment within your package, and then use it like a named list within your package functions:

   ```r
   E <- new.env(parent = emptyenv())
   myfunc <- function(...) {
     # do something
     E$COUNTS <- E$COUNTS + 1
   }
   otherfunc <- function(...) {
     E$COUNTS <- E$COUNTS + 1
   }
   ```

   We do not need the `get`/`assign` pair of functions, since `E` (a horrible name, chosen for its brevity) should be visible to all functions in your package. If you don't need the user to have access, then keep it unexported. If you want users to be able to access it, then exporting it via the normal package mechanisms should work.

Note that with both of these, if the user unloads and reloads the package, the `COUNTS` value will be lost/reset.

I'll list provide a third option, in case the user wants/needs direct access, or you don't want to do this type of value management within your package.

3. Make the user provide it at all times. For this, add an argument to every function that needs it, and have the user pass an environment. I recommend that because most arguments are passed by-value, but environments allow referential semantics (pass by-reference).

   For instance, in your package:

   ```r
   myfunc <- function(..., countenv) {
     stopifnot(is.environment(countenv))
     # do something
     countenv$COUNT <- countenv$COUNT + 1
   }
   otherfunc <- function(..., countenv) {
     countenv$COUNT <- countenv$COUNT + 1
   }
   new_countenv <- function(init = 0) {
     E <- new.env(parent = emptyenv())
     E$COUNT <- init
     E
   }
   ```

   where `new_countenv` is really just a convenience function.

   The user would then use your package as:

   ```r
   mycount <- new_countenv()
   myfunc(..., countenv = mycount)
   otherfunc(..., countenv = mycount)
   ```

Comment: Thank you for sharing multiple solutions. This will be very useful as I make progress on my package. Cheers!